# yum is asking the kernel version which is already there

Tags: kernel, centos, upgrade, yum

I have a server with centos 5.3 x86_64 on it. I am trying to install some asterisk modules on this server using yum. So yum asked me to upgrade my kernel to "kernel-2.6.18-308.11.1.el5"
 Then i have upgraded the kernel using centos-plus repository as the required kernel was not available on base repo. Now after restarting i have tried again to install the same modules using yum but it is asking again for the "kernel-2.6.18-308.11.1.el5". Yum says:

```
Missing Dependency: kernel-x86_64 = 2.6.18-308.11.1.el5 is needed by package
```

I have checked the kernel using "uname -r" command and it is showing :

```
# uname -r
2.6.18-308.11.1.el5.centos.plus
```

Then i saw the difference that mine installed kernel has *.centos.plus appended in the its name. that might be the reason yum is not recognizing the kernel.

Does any have the solution of this problem.? How can i make the yum see the installed kernel version?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at the running kernel with `uname`. Yum is looking at the RPM package database. It's very possible that you've done something so that you've got the kernel actually installed but it's missing from the database. Reinstalling (as you've done) is the easiest way to recover from this if you're not highly knowledgeable about how this all works.

But, going back a step: to see the kernels yum knows about, run:

```
yum list kernel
```

If the kernel you're looking for isn't in the list of installed packages, there's the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have a 32bit kernel installed (the tag "x86_64" is missing in uname -r) and the requirement is for the 64bit kernel.

Example output for 64bit kernel:

```
# uname -r
2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64
```

Comment: The kernel installed is 64 bit. THe output of uname -a is "2.6.18-308.11.1.el5.centos.plus #1 SMP Tue Jul 10 16:44:19 EDT 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"     i guess the issue is suffix of centos.plus in the end of kernel. so its not showing x86_64. If there is any way to change the name from "2.6.18-308.11.1.el5.centos.plus" to "2.6.18-308.11.1.el5" then that might help. Thanks for your answer

Comment: Ultimately i have to reinstall my server from scratch and things are working good now